# EF LINQ outer join not using conditional values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In the following C# EF LINQ code, the field IcasSemester is always rendering as "yes".

```
public static IQueryable<EnrolmentSummaryViewModel> GetQueryable(EducorDbRepo repo, int? userId, int? semesterId)
{
    return from enrolment in repo.EnrolmentQueries.GetAllBase(userId)
        join t in repo.Tenants.GetAll() on enrolment.TenantId equals t.Id
        join u in repo.Users.GetAll() on enrolment.UserId equals u.Id
        join up in repo.UserProfiles.GetAll() on enrolment.UserId equals up.UserId
        join s1 in repo.Semesters.GetAll() on enrolment.SemesterId equals s1.Id into s2
        from s in s2.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where (semesterId == null || enrolment.SemesterId == semesterId)
        orderby enrolment.EnrolmentDate descending, enrolment.Created descending
        select new EnrolmentSummaryViewModel
        {
            Id = enrolment.Id,
            TenantId = enrolment.TenantId,
            Tenant = t.Name,
            UserId = enrolment.UserId,
            StudentEmail = u.Email,
            StudentFirstName = up.FirstName,
            StudentLastName = up.LastName,
            StudentFullName = up.FirstName + " " + up.LastName,
            IcasSemester = enrolment.SemesterId != null ? "yes" : "no",
            SemesterId = enrolment.SemesterId,
            AmountPaid = enrolment.DiscountedCost,
            TotalCost = enrolment.OriginalCost,
            Status = enrolment.Status,
            EnrolmentDate = enrolment.EnrolmentDate,
            Created = enrolment.Created,
            Modified = enrolment.Modified,
            EnrolmentSourceId = enrolment.EnrolmentSourceId,
            OverallStatusId = enrolment.OverallStatusId,
            PaymentMethodId = enrolment.PaymentMethodId
        };
}
```

The outer join is working correctly, but the conditional evaluation is getting hard-coded into the final SQL (from Sql Profiler):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[TenantId] AS [TenantId], 
    [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Project1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Project1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Project1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[SemesterId] AS [SemesterId], 
    [Project1].[DiscountedCost] AS [DiscountedCost], 
    [Project1].[OriginalCost] AS [OriginalCost], 
    [Project1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Project1].[EnrolmentDate] AS [EnrolmentDate], 
    [Project1].[Created] AS [Created], 
    [Project1].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
    [Project1].[EnrolmentSourceId] AS [EnrolmentSourceId], 
    [Project1].[OverallStatusId] AS [OverallStatusId], 
    [Project1].[PaymentMethodId] AS [PaymentMethodId]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[TenantId] AS [TenantId], 
        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
        [Extent1].[OverallStatusId] AS [OverallStatusId], 
        [Extent1].[SemesterId] AS [SemesterId], 
        [Extent1].[EnrolmentDate] AS [EnrolmentDate], 
        [Extent1].[OriginalCost] AS [OriginalCost], 
        [Extent1].[DiscountedCost] AS [DiscountedCost], 
        [Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
        [Extent1].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
        [Extent1].[EnrolmentSourceId] AS [EnrolmentSourceId], 
        [Extent1].[PaymentMethodId] AS [PaymentMethodId], 
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent3].[Email] AS [Email], 
        [Extent4].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
        [Extent4].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent4].[FirstName] IS NULL) THEN N'''' ELSE [Extent4].[FirstName] END + N'' '' + CASE WHEN ([Extent4].[LastName] IS NULL) THEN N'''' ELSE [Extent4].[LastName] END AS [C1], 
        N''yes'' AS [C2]
        FROM    [dbo].[Enrolments] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tenants] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TenantId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent3].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[UserProfiles] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent4].[UserId]
        WHERE @p__linq__0 IS NULL OR [Extent1].[SemesterId] = @p__linq__1
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[EnrolmentDate] DESC, [Project1].[Created] DESC
    OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY ',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 int',@p__linq__0=NULL,@p__linq__1=NULL
```

I've also tried variations of the conditional clause, such as:

```
IcasSemester = s != null ? "yes" : "no"
```

How can I get that conditional field to evaluate correctly?

Comment: I'll ask a really silly follow-up question here: I assume `IcasSemester` field of `Enrollment` table is marked nullable in your EF mapping, right?

Comment: `IcasSemester` is a string field on the view model. `Enrolment.SemesterId` is nullable and is marked as optional in the configuration.

Comment: Issue seems to be with the where condition. What is the expected output when the nullable int variable semesterId is null? try changing the where condition to `where (enrolment.SemesterId == semesterId)`

Comment: I've tried dropping the where condition before, and there is no change to the results or the data.  The where condition is used to provide an optional filter.  In my scenario I'm passing in semesterId as null, so all the rows are rendering because `null == null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the configuration for the Enrolment entity.  The following line was affecting the way the SQL was being rendered (`HasRequired` should have been `HasOptional`):

```
HasRequired(p => p.Semester).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.SemesterId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```